# IIS WCF Service Accesed via JAVA with NTLM Authentication

Tags: java, .net, wcf, ntlm

We have a WCF Service hosted in IIS 6 with Integrated Windows Authentication turned on under Directory Security.  Consuming this service from a .NET Windows client the cached NTLM credentials flow to the Server PC and things work great.  We would like to have the same occur when a Java client accesses the service (via the WSDL generated objects) from a Windows PC.  Everything we have scoured on the net seems to state that we will not need to hard code the username/password into the Java code if we leverage the Sun java.net.authenticator and run the process on the Windows platform.  Is this true?  We have a solution using Axis 2.0 and its proprietary NTLM authenticator, however we had to hard code the username/password.  Ideally, we'd like the NTLM cached credentials to flow automatically to the server.  It seems like this should be possible since the Java process is running on a Windows PC.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an open source library, http://spnego.sourceforge.net/protected_soap_service.html, that does exactly what you want to do.